# Hyperparameter tuning using Keras Tuner raised value error

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to use Keras Tuner to pick my model's optimal set of hyperparameters. My code raised:

```
ValueError": Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: 
   expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 867000 but received input with shape (None, 100)
```

I also tried with `model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=X.shape[1:]))` and it raised the same error.

Label encode

```
encoder = LabelEncoder()
df["subtype"] = encoder.fit_transform(df[["subtype"]])
```

Retrieve features and target

```
X = df.iloc[:,7:1007] # 1000 features  
y = df[["subtype"]]
```

Train-test-val split

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=1) # 0.25 x 0.8 = 0.2
```

Define model

```
# Define Sequential model 
def get_model(hp):
    model = keras.Sequential()
    
    model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=X.shape))
    
    # Tune the number of units in the first Dense layer
    hp_units = hp.Int('units', min_value=30, max_value=len(X.T), step=32)
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=hp_units, activation='relu'))
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10))
    
    # Tune the learning rate for the optimizer
    # Choose an optimal value from 0.01, 0.001, or 0.0001
    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])
    
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate), 
                  loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    
    return model
```

Early stopping

```
es_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)
```

Feature selection

```
selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=100) # Retrieve 100 best features
selected_features_subtype = selector.fit_transform(X_train, y_train.values.ravel())
```

Instantiate the tuner

```
tuner = kt.Hyperband(get_model,
                     objective='val_accuracy',
                     max_epochs=10,
                     factor=3)
```

Hyperparameter search:

```
tuner.search(selected_features_subtype, y_train, validation_split=0.5,  batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=[es_callback])
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17/1635591259.py in <module>
----> 1 tuner.search(selected_features_subtype, y_train, validation_split=0.5,  batch_size=batch_size, callbacks=[es_callback])
      2 
      3 # Get the optimal hyperparameters
      4 best_hps=tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]
      5 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_tuner/engine/base_tuner.py in search(self, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
    177 
    178             self.on_trial_begin(trial)
--> 179             results = self.run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
    180             # `results` is None indicates user updated oracle in `run_trial()`.
    181             if results is None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_tuner/tuners/hyperband.py in run_trial(self, trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
    382             fit_kwargs["epochs"] = hp.values["tuner/epochs"]
    383             fit_kwargs["initial_epoch"] = hp.values["tuner/initial_epoch"]
--> 384         return super(Hyperband, self).run_trial(trial, *fit_args, **fit_kwargs)
    385 
    386     def _build_model(self, hp):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_tuner/engine/tuner.py in run_trial(self, trial, *args, **kwargs)
    292             callbacks.append(model_checkpoint)
    293             copied_kwargs["callbacks"] = callbacks
--> 294             obj_value = self._build_and_fit_model(trial, *args, **copied_kwargs)
    295 
    296             histories.append(obj_value)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_tuner/engine/tuner.py in _build_and_fit_model(self, trial, *args, **kwargs)
    220         hp = trial.hyperparameters
    221         model = self._try_build(hp)
--> 222         results = self.hypermodel.fit(hp, model, *args, **kwargs)
    223         return tuner_utils.convert_to_metrics_dict(
    224             results, self.oracle.objective, "HyperModel.fit()"

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_tuner/engine/hypermodel.py in fit(self, hp, model, *args, **kwargs)
    135             If return a float, it should be the `objective` value.
    136         """
--> 137         return model.fit(*args, **kwargs)
    138 
    139 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1182                 _r=1):
   1183               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1184               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1185               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1186                 context.async_wait()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    758     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    759         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 760             *args, **kwds))
    761 
    762     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3064       args, kwargs = None, None
   3065     with self._lock:
-> 3066       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3067     return graph_function
   3068 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3461 
   3462           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3463           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3464           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3465 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3306             arg_names=arg_names,
   3307             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3308             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3309         self._function_attributes,
   3310         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)
   1005         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
   1006 
-> 1007       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1008 
   1009       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    666         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    667         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 668           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    669         return out
    670 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:787 train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1037 __call__
        outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/sequential.py:369 call
        return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py:415 call
        inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py:550 _run_internal_graph
        outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py:1020 __call__
        input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py:254 assert_input_compatibility
        ' but received input with shape ' + display_shape(x.shape))

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 867000 but received input with shape (None, 100)
```

Sample data (as dict):

```
    {'cg00000289': {'TCGA-5P-A9JW-01A': 0.619047033443068,
      'TCGA-5P-A9JY-01A': 0.662345356057447,
      'TCGA-5P-A9JZ-01A': 0.699464419990523,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K0-01A': 0.581701228463189,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K2-01A': 0.673198201701496,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K3-01A': 0.626858745753386,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K4-01A': 0.68070511240185,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K6-01A': 0.736978843263676,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K8-01A': 0.520786654021559,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K9-01A': 0.630167782543268,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KA-01A': 0.626926559177059,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KC-01A': 0.630977089669812,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KE-01A': 0.67563913188817,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KF-01A': 0.645760654461395,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KH-01A': 0.743286554209644,
      'TCGA-6D-AA2E-01A': 0.664370540359405,
      'TCGA-A3-3357-01A': 0.604326417072586,
      'TCGA-A3-3358-01A': 0.458291671200214,
      'TCGA-A3-3367-01A': 0.643363591881443,
      'TCGA-A3-3370-01A': 0.75808536817831},
     'cg00000292': {'TCGA-5P-A9JW-01A': 0.833751448211989,
      'TCGA-5P-A9JY-01A': 0.761479643484317,
      'TCGA-5P-A9JZ-01A': 0.555219387831784,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K0-01A': 0.911434986725676,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K2-01A': 0.592839496707225,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K3-01A': 0.728724740061591,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K4-01A': 0.871647081931081,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K6-01A': 0.687137365325043,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K8-01A': 0.377068349756215,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K9-01A': 0.885089826740071,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KA-01A': 0.678749255227915,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KC-01A': 0.82812139328519,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KE-01A': 0.864590733749797,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KF-01A': 0.858070865799283,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KH-01A': 0.914435928566657,
      'TCGA-6D-AA2E-01A': 0.502154665104261,
      'TCGA-A3-3357-01A': 0.662047197870235,
      'TCGA-A3-3358-01A': 0.837059251611538,
      'TCGA-A3-3367-01A': 0.519939858249351,
      'TCGA-A3-3370-01A': 0.515743234863198},
     'cg00000321': {'TCGA-5P-A9JW-01A': 0.489674207394165,
      'TCGA-5P-A9JY-01A': 0.558997284357574,
      'TCGA-5P-A9JZ-01A': 0.169654991100549,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K0-01A': 0.524017780921585,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K2-01A': 0.613973121455874,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K3-01A': 0.695670625292722,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K4-01A': 0.54705053331032,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K6-01A': 0.430048300391044,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K8-01A': 0.198107812192402,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K9-01A': 0.688004412660976,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KA-01A': 0.463728628068311,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KC-01A': 0.195610858899826,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KE-01A': 0.550900635535007,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KF-01A': 0.183061803083559,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KH-01A': 0.0687041391027568,
      'TCGA-6D-AA2E-01A': 0.570614767869701,
      'TCGA-A3-3357-01A': 0.680216582417148,
      'TCGA-A3-3358-01A': 0.288408070866453,
      'TCGA-A3-3367-01A': 0.68957300320214,
      'TCGA-A3-3370-01A': 0.432450706527388},
     'cg00000363': {'TCGA-5P-A9JW-01A': 0.276273359465442,
      'TCGA-5P-A9JY-01A': 0.25703867804956,
      'TCGA-5P-A9JZ-01A': 0.0981746197111535,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K0-01A': 0.569434380074143,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K2-01A': 0.229164840583894,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K3-01A': 0.819181728250669,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K4-01A': 0.385400157144987,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K6-01A': 0.121114850921845,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K8-01A': 0.0913002964111161,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K9-01A': 0.157709640291589,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KA-01A': 0.182786461024344,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KC-01A': 0.413992919815649,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KE-01A': 0.461011690059099,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KF-01A': 0.206300754004666,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KH-01A': 0.105913974360403,
      'TCGA-6D-AA2E-01A': 0.414195666341229,
      'TCGA-A3-3357-01A': 0.236700230821645,
      'TCGA-A3-3358-01A': 0.26841943012007,
      'TCGA-A3-3367-01A': 0.324092383012077,
      'TCGA-A3-3370-01A': 0.20675761437022},
     'cg00000622': {'TCGA-5P-A9JW-01A': 0.0127307580597565,
      'TCGA-5P-A9JY-01A': 0.0120665526567922,
      'TCGA-5P-A9JZ-01A': 0.0129414663486043,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K0-01A': 0.0151053469374601,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K2-01A': 0.0147191458229104,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K3-01A': 0.0128586680833482,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K4-01A': 0.0131839246367822,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K6-01A': 0.0145337257462313,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K8-01A': 0.0131548295351121,
      'TCGA-5P-A9K9-01A': 0.0164371867221858,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KA-01A': 0.0153209540816947,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KC-01A': 0.0146341900882511,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KE-01A': 0.0138002584809048,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KF-01A': 0.012958575912875,
      'TCGA-5P-A9KH-01A': 0.0142346121115625,
      'TCGA-6D-AA2E-01A': 0.0139666701044385,
      'TCGA-A3-3357-01A': 0.0082183731354049,
      'TCGA-A3-3358-01A': 0.0143527756424356,
      'TCGA-A3-3367-01A': 0.0100636145864037,
      'TCGA-A3-3370-01A': 0.0108528842825329},
     'type': {'TCGA-5P-A9JW-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9JY-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9JZ-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K0-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K2-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K3-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K4-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K6-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K8-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K9-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9KA-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9KC-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9KE-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9KF-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-5P-A9KH-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-6D-AA2E-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-A3-3357-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-A3-3358-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-A3-3367-01A': 'tumor',
      'TCGA-A3-3370-01A': 'tumor'},
     'subtype': {'TCGA-5P-A9JW-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9JY-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9JZ-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K0-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K2-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K3-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K4-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K6-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K8-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9K9-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9KA-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9KC-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9KE-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9KF-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-5P-A9KH-01A': 'KIRP',
      'TCGA-6D-AA2E-01A': 'KIRC',
      'TCGA-A3-3357-01A': 'KIRC',
      'TCGA-A3-3358-01A': 'KIRC',
      'TCGA-A3-3367-01A': 'KIRC',
      'TCGA-A3-3370-01A': 'KIRC'}}
```

Comment: Change this line `model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=X.shape))` to this `model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=X.shape[1:]))` may work.

Comment: @Kaveh it still raises the error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that units=hp_units in the last (output layer) is an int number, also change the activation='relu' to softmax. Hope this can work